# Memory usage with future and containers in Qt / MinGW

Tags: c++, stl, mingw, future

Consider the following test code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::array;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef unsigned int uint;


double TestFutures()
{
    return 1;
}

void DoWork()
{
    const uint nPoints=50;
    const uint nThreads=100;
    vector<double> results(nThreads,0);

    // For each data point...
    for (uint k=0; k<nPoints; ++k) {
        // ... launch the threads
        vector<std::future<double> > values;
        for (uint w=0; w<nThreads; ++w) {
            values.push_back(std::async(TestFutures));
        }
        // ... and now read the results
        for (uint w=0; w<nThreads; ++w) {
            results[w]+= values[w].get();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const uint nTimes=50;

    for (uint k=0; k<nTimes; ++k) {
        cout << "Cycle: " << k << endl;
        DoWork();
    }
}
```

I compile it in Qt 5.0.1, MinGW 4.7.2, Qt Creator 2.6.2. Then I run it, either in the debugger, or stand alone, release or debug version. If I monitor the memory usage, it increases monotonically during the execution of the loops. By increasing the variable *nTimes* in the *main* function, I can make the program allocate an arbitrary amount of memory (I have tried up to 1Gb).
I monitor the memory usage with task manager or procexp.

If I then take the same code and compile it and run it under MS Visual Studio Express 2012, the memory usage remains stable during the loop. This, I think, is what you would expect, as the vector of futures should be destroyed after each *k-iteration*.

I am not sure, but I believe the problem then lies on Qt or MinGW. Actually, I suspect it might be a problem with MinGW. But before I report it to the developers, I would like to ask other kind users to verify this issue. (I'd love to be wrong!)

Just to let you know, I still have the same issue if I substitute the vector of futures with an array, i.e. this *DoWork()* routine:

```
void DoWork()
{
    const uint nPoints=50;
    const uint nThreads=100;
    vector<double> results(nThreads,0);

    // For each data point...
    for (uint k=0; k<nPoints; ++k) {
        // ... launch the threads
        array<std::future<double>,nThreads> values;
        for (uint w=0; w<nThreads; ++w) {
            values[w]=std::async(TestFutures);
        }
        // ... and now read the results
        for (uint w=0; w<nThreads; ++w) {
            results[w]+= values[w].get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no QT code in your example... what am I missing?

Comment: There's no Qt specific code in this example. You can compile it as Non-Qt, Plain C++ project. Thanks

Comment: So why are you thinking that Qt might cause the high memory usage when it is not even used? I think you should remove the Qt tag.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, I suspect that the problem is with MinGW, but I am not 100% sure that there's no relation whatsoever to Qt: a missing compile flag, a wrong configuration, etc. Unlikely, but can't rule it out. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Test the same qt project using visual studio instead of mingw, that would give you a definitive answer for whether it's Qt's fault.  I also highly suspect this is a compiler issue.

Comment: Tried your code with gcc 4.7.2 on Linux (using qmake). No increase in memory, no reported leaks in valgrind. So I'd expect mingw/the STL impl. it comes with.

Comment: Note, with gcc on Linux one may need to explicitly pass `std::launch::async` to the async call since it defaults to deferred execution (on any system I've been able to try it on).

Even with that I don't see increased memory usage with increasing `ntimes`; so I also suspect MinGW's implementation (probably of futures).  However, I have previously observed some excessive virtual memory usage if you keep a bunch of futures (from async) lying around; enough to OOM-kill my process in fact.

Comment: Apologies for the long silence. Thanks to all who made comments. I am in the process of verifying a couple of things and submitting them to the appropriate people. So far, the most likely culprit is MinGW.

Comment: This reminds me of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46455 but that was fixed in GCC 4.6.0